# Is there a way of getting variables from a prime class inside declared class?

Tags: php, oop, variables

for example -

```
class wow
{
  public $foo = 5;
  public function __construct()
 {
   $sub_class = new sub();
 }

}

    class sub
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    echo $this->foo;
  }
}

$wow = new wow();
```

Is there a way of doing this?

why the f*** always people minusing my questions? What is your problem? This site is for asking questions, if you have a problem so don't come to this site.

Comment: I believe that class sub would need to extend class wow for it to inherit the properties of wow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding on from my comment.. try this

```
class wow
{
    public $foo = 5;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $sub_class = new sub();
    }
}

class sub extends wow
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->foo;
    }
}

$wow = new wow();
```

Comment: Well, it is working but now I have a problem with my pdo class.
It says that there are "too many connections." probably because of the extends, what I should do?

Comment: Maybe time for another question?

Comment: Or.. it might be time to learn the singleton pattern for database connection resources! Give me a minute I'll find you a link

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/ Somewhere on this page is an overview of the singleton design pattern, which in the case of database connections might be just what you're looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You should extend the parent class

```
class wow
{
    public $foo = 5;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $sub_class = new sub();
    }

}

class sub extends wow
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->foo;
    }
}

$wow = new wow();
```

This will return 5.

And you have other errors in your code

```
class sub()
```

Should be

```
class sub
```

And

```
public __construct()
```

Should be

```
public function __construct()
```